# Response from controller not handled correctly with jquery

Tags: jquery, spring-restcontroller

In a spring boot application with rest architecture

I try to do a ajax call

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "PATCH",
    url: getHostName() + "/members/" + memberId + "/contracts/" + contractId + "?status=CANCEL",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Basic " + $.cookie('authorization')
    },
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
      $('#modalSaveSuccess').modal('show');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status) {
      checkError(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

In the controller,

```
 @PatchMapping(value = "/members/{memberId}/contracts/{contractId}")
 public ResponseEntity updateContractStatus(@PathVariable("memberId") Long memberId, @PathVariable("contractId") Long contractId, @RequestParam("status") StatusEnum status) {

     if (status == StatusEnum.CANCEL) {
         contractService.cancelContract(contractId);
     }
     return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
 }
```

When i debug i see that return HttpStatus.OK

In javascript that go in the error section with a status of 200 and with a statusText "parsererror"

Response header

```
HTTP/1.1 200
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 17 Dec 2016 18:53:13 GMT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `dataType: 'json'` but you are not returning json. Please remove that line and check the result.